# How to make sure that an app gets installed for one device only in Android?

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to implement an feature in one of my app so that it can be installed only on one device i guess trying with Device ID is one method Or are there any other methods to do so.......

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want this, but checking the Device ID against a hardcoded one is an option. Then you can run/exit the app depending on the result

Comment: I wanna check becoz my app is for premium users so i dont wanna that a user buys it for one premium amount and keep using it on multiple devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you are putting this on the Play store, users can always download any paid software again, as long as any device is linked with the same Google account used to purchase the app. This is designed to stop people losing apps should they get a new device etc and paying for it multiple times.

After reading your comments I believe what you wish the app to do potentially breaks Google Play TOC's. That said, you have not really described what you want to do well enough.

Comment: No dude all i am asking is how should i make it possible to keep it single user property say you paid for an app which you need but someone somehow got the apk file from your smartphone and started using it i just wanna prevent this now i cannot make it through email registration system becoz it doesnt require Net services it is just a simple customer management thing

Answer (score 0):

You could require the user to register with an email address before using the app. Maintain a database of emails that have been used to register the app and if an email has already been used, block them.

Note that while this is technically a solution to the question you asked, setting a limit like this is just going to irritate your users and is more likely to cause sales to go down (the few who buy will leave negative reviews, causing others to not buy), not up.